# Specify SUM column when using a CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case

I'm basically trying to sum up the values of a specific column. RIght now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
DATE(paid_at) AS day,
(SELECT sum(shipping_costs) from orders where shipping_method = 'mondial_relais' and DATE(paid_at) = day) as mr_revenue_real
FROM orders
WHERE MONTH(paid_at) = 10
AND YEAR(paid_at) = 2011
GROUP BY day;
```

I want to replace the subquery for `mr_revenue_real` to improve performance but I'm not sure how to do that. This is what I had in mind:
`sum(case when hipping_method = 'mondial_relais' and DATE(paid_at) = day then 1 end) as mr_revenue_real`but this won't work because I'm not specifying anywhere that I need the sum of the shipping_costs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sum(case when  shipping_method='mondial_relais' then shipping_costs else 0 end)
```

the full query:

```
SELECT
 DATE(paid_at) AS day,
 sum(case when  shipping_method='mondial_relais' then shipping_costs else 0 end)
FROM orders
WHERE MONTH(paid_at) = 10 AND YEAR(paid_at) = 2011
GROUP BY day;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
    SELECT
       DATE(paid_at) AS day,
       sum(case when shipping_method = 'mondial_relais' 
           then shipping_costs end) as mr_revenue_real
    FROM orders
    WHERE MONTH(paid_at) = 10
    AND YEAR(paid_at) = 2011
    GROUP BY day;
```

(You don't need to specify `DATE(paid_at) = day`, because you are already grouping by `DATE(paid_at) AS day`.)

Answer (score 0):

First, replace:

```
WHERE MONTH(paid_at) = 10 AND YEAR(paid_at) = 2011
```

with:

```
WHERE paid_at >= '2011-10-01'
  AND paid_at <  '2011-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

so, if you have an index on `paid_at`, it will be used and the query will not have to scan the whole table, nor call the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions for every row.

---

Second, you don't need the subquery in the `SELECT` list. You can use something like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(paid_at) AS day,
    SUM( CASE WHEN shipping_method = 'mondial_relais'
                  THEN shipping_costs
              ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS mr_revenue_real
FROM orders
WHERE paid_at >= '2011-10-01'
  AND paid_at <  '2011-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY DATE(paid_at)
```

---

You could also use this query which will probably be faster with a `(shipping_method, paid_at)` index. This, however, will not show any days that have no order with `shipping_method = 'mondial_relais'`:

```
SELECT
    DATE(paid_at) AS day,
    SUM(shipping_costs) AS mr_revenue_real
FROM orders
WHERE shipping_method = 'mondial_relais'
  AND paid_at >= '2011-10-01'
  AND paid_at <  '2011-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY DATE(paid_at)
```

Comment: Any reason why this is better?